# how to assign each block an Id to differentiate between blocks inside a canvas and fetch data according to that id

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, canvas, react-hooks

Hello Fellow Developers,

I'm new to react and canvas api, I want to create 10k blocks(square) of particular dimensions and each block is different from one another by ID. I have created 10k blocks
of 100 * 100 rows and columns and each box is 10 * 10.

1. Now what I want is to assign an ID to each box to identify that particular box that I select onClick and read data from smart contract
2. Once the ID is selected I want to able to select multiple boxes using input fields, eg, I selected box# 4 and in input fields I have to select width and height, so when I select width 5 block numbers 5 6 7 8 9 in x-direction will also get selected, similarly if I select height 2 then  including 4 one more box is selected in y-direction.

Now these selection can only happen if that box is available to select if its value is false, no-one can select that box no matter the height and width.

I don't know how to assign an ID please anyone can help me in this, It'll be great help

Reference Website to understand my points: https://milliondollartokenpage.com/

```
Code is attached that I've done so far:
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ahmedzafar/d3twnfe1/1/

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: @ChrisG coordinates of the click event changes with the page width and height, isn't it? I need to get the same id whenever I click on a particular box

Comment: Yes, but your code is using a fixed canvas width of 1000 pixels, i.e. 100 boxes. I doubt this is going to change because you'll want to sell rectangles of boxes, right? So you need a fixed number of boxes per row.

Comment: Right now the ID of the click can be calculated by `Math.floor(y / 10) * 100 + Math.floor(x / 10)`

Comment: @MuhammadAhmedzafar  see if this is what you are looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/heldersepu/078ztk5h/28/

Comment: @HelderSepulveda yeah this is what I'm looking maybe I can customize it even more as I need to make it more advance like I have to be able to select multiple boxes and then upload an image on that box plus if I clicked on that box a sidebar should open with a description of that box

Comment: @ChrisG I got your point and thanks alot for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Canvas has no concept of "ID" for the elements that are drawn, you have to keep track of that...

But canvas as good options to help us deal with this obstacle, my favorite is Path2d:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D/Path2D

Here is a starting point:

```js
class Shape {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.path = new Path2D();
    this.path.arc(x, y, 16, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  }

  draw(ctx, pos) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = ctx.isPointInPath(this.path, pos.x, pos.y)? "red": "tan"
    ctx.fill(this.path);
  }
}

function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return { x: evt.clientX - rect.left, y: evt.clientY - rect.top };
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

shapes = []
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  shapes.push(new Shape(50 + i * 40, 40))
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  shapes.forEach(s => { s.draw(ctx, getMousePos(canvas, evt)) })
}, false);

shapes.forEach(s => { s.draw(ctx, { x: 0, y: 0}) })
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=500 height=150></canvas>
```

On that example we can see I used `Path2D` and the `isPointInPath` to determine if the mouse is on an element, and we change the fill color accordingly.

---

Here is another example, this time we detect if user clicked in one of our shapes, and just output some info to the console.

```js
class Shape {
  constructor(name, x, y) {
    this.obj = {name, x, y}
    this.path = new Path2D();
    this.path.rect(x, y, 50, 50);
  }

  draw(ctx) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.stroke(this.path);
    ctx.strokeText(this.obj.name, this.obj.x +10, this.obj.y +20)
  }
}

function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return { x: evt.clientX - rect.left, y: evt.clientY - rect.top };
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

shapes = []
shapes.push(new Shape("A", 10, 10))
shapes.push(new Shape("B", 80, 10))
shapes.push(new Shape("C", 150, 10))

canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function(evt) {
  var pos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
  shapes.forEach(s => { 
    if (ctx.isPointInPath(s.path, pos.x, pos.y))
      console.log(s.obj)
  })
}, false);

shapes.forEach(s => { s.draw(ctx) })
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=100></canvas>
```

My examples are not React/NodeJs but...
I hope you can easily integrate this concept in your project.

---

I had a bit of time to play with your sample, I made some changes here two versions:

- https://jsfiddle.net/heldersepu/078ztk5h/28/
- https://jsfiddle.net/heldersepu/078ztk5h/47/

Comment: thanks for the answer this is something I'm looking for getBoundingClientRect() is not working on react and sidebar is also not opening when adding onClick event listener, I'm still working on it. I've identified each block by clicking on it only problem is the sidebar not opening when clicked on canvas

Comment: @MuhammadAhmedzafar ... What do you mean `getBoundingClientRect` is not working?? it works fine in my jsfiddle examples  ...  and the sidebar not opening is completely different problem; remember stackoverflow is not a coding service, we are not going to code an application for you, the expectation here is one question focused on one problem only, if you have other issues ask another question  ... and please keep your code minimal, read this for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example